# python3.6 start 1 million requests with aiohttp and asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to make 1 million requests with aiohttp and asyncio continuously in 10 times which 10k at each time. When I print the start time of each request, I found that the 1 million requests are NOT start at a very closed time but in serval minutes. In my understanding, the 1 million requests will be sent without any wait(or just say in microseconds?) Hope someone can help me give a suggestion how to change the code, and my code is as below. Thanks in advance!

```
import asyncio
import requests
import json
import pymysql
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from datetime import datetime
import uvloop


# login config
URL_LOGIN = "https://test.com/user/login"
APP_ID = "sample_app_id"
APP_SECRET = "sample_secret"


async def login_user(phone, password, session, i):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    h = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    data = {
        "phone": phone,
        "password": password,
        "appid": APP_ID,
        "appsecret": APP_SECRET
            }
    try:
        async with session.post(url=URL_LOGIN, data=json.dumps(data), headers=h) as response:
            r = await response.read()
            end_time = datetime.now()
            cost = (end_time-start_time).seconds
            msg = "number %d request，start_time：%s, cost_time: %d, response: %s\n" % (i, start_time, cost, r.decode())
            print("running %d" % i, datetime.now())
    except Exception as e:
        print("running %d" % i)
        msg = "number %d request raise error" % i+str(e)+"\n"
    with open("log", "a+") as f:
        f.write(msg)


async def bound_login(sem, phone, password, session, i):
    async with sem:
        await login_user(phone, password, session, i)


async def run_login(num):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10000)
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(num):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_login(sem, str(18300000000+i), "123456", session, i))
            tasks.append(task)
        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses

start = datetime.now()
number = 100000
loop = uvloop.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run_login(number))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I print the start time of each request, I found that the 1 million requests are NOT start at a very closed time but in serval minutes.

Your code does issue a total of 1 million requests, but with the constraint that no more than 10 thousand of them runs in parallel at any given time. This is like having 10k request slots at your disposal - the first 10,000 requests will be started immediately, but the 10,001st will have to wait for a previous request to finish so it can get a free slot.

This is why 1 million requests cannot start instantaneously or near-instantaneously, most of them have to wait for some download to finish, and that takes time.

> In my understanding, the 1 million requests will be sent **without any wait**

The current code explicitly makes the requests wait in order to prevent more than 10k of them running in parallel. If you really want to (try to) make a million parallel requests, remove the semaphore and create the `ClientSession` using a [connector](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#tcpconnector) with `limit` set to `None`.

However, be aware that maintaining a million open connections will likely not work due to limits of the operating system and the hardware. (You should still be able to *start* the connections near-instantaneously, but I'd expect most of them to exit with an exception shortly afterwards.)

Comment: Please update your answer to mention that `ClientSession` has embedded semaphore functionality with limit to 100 concurrent connections: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#tcpconnector `limit=100` parameter

Comment: @user4815162342 one more question: what do u mean by "but the 10,001st will have to wait for a previous request to finish so it can get a free slot."? So the "finish" means the server has returns a response to client or just the requests need to sent before have been sent and now there are free slots left for a new batch?

Comment: @LauReal "Finish" means the `async with sem` block needs to have exited. In your case that means that `login_user` has to finish (either by returning a value or by raising an exception). Since `login_user` reads the response, then that's what "finish" means. But that's up to you as the author of the code - you could also start `login_user` "in the background" using `loop.create_task` or (more simply get rid of the semaphore).

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks very much, now I have a little understand Semaphore.